# Powershell GUI Imported text file missing newline/carriage return

Tags: powershell, user-interface, textbox

I have a powershell GUI which imports a text file and displays it in a textbox when a button is clicked

But even though the text file contains one entry per line when it gets displayed in the textbox it is all on one line...

The text file looks like this-

[image: TXT]

But when I import it it looks like this-

[image: GUI]

This is the code I am using-

```
$button_hosts = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button_hosts.Text = "Hosts"
$button_hosts.Width = 60
$button_hosts.Height = 25
$button_hosts.location = new-object system.drawing.point(20,55)
$button_hosts.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$mydocs = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
$button_hosts.Add_Click({
    $textBox_hosts.Text = Get-Filename "$mydocs" txt
    $textBox_hostlist.Text = Get-Content $textBox_hosts.Text
})
$GUI.controls.Add($button_hosts)
```

Any idea how to get it to display the same? I cant add any extra data to the txt file as it is an output from another program

Comment: In Notepad++, go to `View` > `Show Symbol` > `Show End of Line` and please update screenshot.

Comment: Try `$textBox_hostlist.Text = Get-Content $textBox_hosts.Text | Out-String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the lines property, not the text property.

```
$textBox_hostlist.Lines = Get-Content $textBox_hosts.Text
```

Comment: Yes! this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` reads the content one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each of which represents a line of content.
The means that you have to join the collection with carriage returns and linefeeds:

```
(Get-Content $textBox_hosts) -Join "`r`n"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your WinForms TextBox, do you have the multiline property set to true?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx

If not, it defaults to single line.